# Is "He gave me a strange look" proper?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, verbs

I am trying to express the following sentence:

> He gave me a strange look.

It sounds strange since he isn't giving me something, but he is showing a strange look on the face.

One of the definitions of the verb "gave" is:

> carry out or perform (a specified action).

That is what I am trying to express with my sentence. But, is "strange look" suitable for this situation.

Or, do I have to say something along the lines of:

> He showed me a strange look.

Comment: Yes, 'gave me a strange look' is fine. We can give things that are not tangible, including looks, glances, smiles, frowns, etc. We would not say 'showed me a strange look'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ok cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> He gave me a strange look.

This is a normal sentence. In fact, it is a very common sentence. I have read it many times before.

In its most basic sense, "giving something a look" means that you are turning your eyes towards it. The action you are carrying out is the act of looking or seeing.

When you look at another *person*, you are also directing your facial expression towards them. Because of this, "a look" also means "an expression on someone's face". "A strange look" is an expression of confusion or disgust.

---

> <strike>He showed me a strange look.</strike>

A native speaker would not use this sentence. I don't know if I can explain why. It is almost like he is saying, "Come over here and see my face. I want to make a strange expression."

Instead, you could say:

> He had a strange look on his face.

This is not quite the same as "He gave me a strange look", because it does not tell you who or what he is looking at.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Note: in the UK, at least, we often say someone gave us a 'funny look', where 'funny' does not mean 'humorous or amusing'. If I used an office meeting to talk about my theories that Martians are living among us and controlling our thoughts, or tried to pay for my groceries in a supermarket using buttons instead of coins, I would get funny looks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That also works in the US.